# arduino output pins collapsing voltage - is it dead?

Tags: arduino, microprocessor, output, pins

After a while i came back to my arduino UNO R3, and attempted most simple program, that sets digital output pin high.

I measured voltage over that pin, and got 5 volts, but when I connected an LED, it didnt light.

I measured the voltage again, and found out, when I connect LED and resistor, Voltage just collapses to 1.8 volts !

I used FOR loop and checked, every output pin does the same.

```
Q: is my arduino uno broken, is there anything i can do?
```

- i have SMD version of atmega328

Comment: It's worth mentioning the type of LED and resistor value that are connected, the voltage from an I/O pin will drop if you're exceeding the recommended current for the pin.

Comment: what value did you use for the resistor?

Comment: oh it was 330ohm, LED is 5mm green, rated at max 20mA but I used same configuration before many times, when I connect that configuration to arduino +5v or even +3.3V it works like charm!

Comment: Can you post your code? My first instinct is that you have not set the pin for output, hence this behaviour. But the code will tell...